# Display Java 8 Time api in this format "HH:mma" (05:53PM) and add set Time with only minutes

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-8, localtime

I want to display / print out time like 
`02:15PM`
and be able to set the time just based on minutes(possibly larger than 59).

This doesn't seem to work:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mma");
    String text = time.format(formatter);
    LocalTime parsedTime = LocalTime.parse(text, formatter);
```

it shows time like `16:15` so its the wrong 12/24 format(and am/pm missing of course)

so far I set the time like this:

```
void setTime(int minutes) {
    time = LocalTime.of(minutes / 60, minutes % 60);
}
```

is there a way to do it in a more elegant way (read: without dividing)?

I do not want to use Joda Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed, use `hh` instead of `HH` for an AM/PM clock. The list of patterns is detailed in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). Example:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(18, 0);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma");
System.out.println(fmt.format(time)); //06:00PM
```

As for creating a time from a number of minutes, you can use:

```
LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plusMinutes(minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace the "HH" with "hh": `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mma");`
2. Slighty more elegant way of setting time by minutes: `LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(minutes * 60)`